# From random sums to random integrals

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

If we have a sequence of random variables with the same expection. so $( X_i)$ and $E[X_j]=E[X_i], \forall i,j$ and $N$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}$. Where $N \perp X_i, \forall i$

Then $\displaystyle E\bigg[ \sum_{n=1}^N X_n \bigg ] = E[N]E[X_1]$.

There is also another equation which holds for variance which I will omit as it adds nothing to the post.

Question: Is there a similar result when summation is replaced by integration? Or a generalization of this?

Comment: The equation you wrote is false in general. You need independence of $N$ and $(X_i)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are correct, I have added that condition.